# Cross spectrum using `cpsd` (matlab) of 2D matrices

Tags: signal-analysis

I'm struggling with [`cpsd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cpsd.html) for 2D matrices. In my test, I've generated two 100x100 matrices (sine waves) `s1` and `p1` with a small phase difference between them. I'm trying to identify the propagation direction using this phase difference, hence using `cpsd`

```
[Psp F] = cpsd(s1,p1....).
```

My guess is that `cpsd` is the one for the job. However I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing. When the crests of `s1` and `p1` are orthogonal to the axis, my script works just fine. However, if they have some angle, instead of two components, let's say in the 1st and 3rd quadrant, I end up with 4 components, in all quadrants. Not good...

I suppose there's something wrong with the way I'm using `cpsd` for matrices. Anyone out there could give me a hand? Many thanks.

This is my code so far

```
[numrow numcol] = size(s1);
for c = 1:numcol
    [Psp1(:,c),F]= cpsd(s1(:,c),p1(:,c),[],[],[],dt,'twosided');
end
for l = 1:numrow
    [Psp2(l,:),F]= cpsd(s1(l,:),p1(l,:),[],[],[],dt,'twosided');
end
Psp=Psp1*Psp2;
F1=F-1/(2*dt); % 
[XF YF] = meshgrid(F, F);      
[XF1 YF1] = meshgrid(F1, F1);
```

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Please let us know how you are calculating `s1` and `p1`.

Comment: Dear Peter K its a simple 2D sine wave, my trouble is with how to use cpsd. Any experience on that? thank you